# Jsoup can't open html page

Tags: java, jsoup, ioexception, http-status-code-400

i'm trying to open a page using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/).
I've tried opening a page like `www.google.com` and printing content using:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

Output is:

```
Google Ricerca Immagini Video Mappe News Shopping Gmail Altro » iGoogle | Cronologia web | Impostazioni | Accedi Italia   Ricerca avanzataStrumenti per le lingue PubblicitàSoluzioni AziendaliTutto su GoogleGoogle.com in English © 2012 - Privacy e Termini
```

if i try opening my page like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test.php?link=http://www.myothersite.com/test/test1-/10968/try.html?params=65%253A12%257C66%253A2%257C39%253A6%257C72%253A5104&rt=nc&_dmd=1&id=p3286.c0.m14&_vc=1&x=11&param1=p and d&sotto_categoria=_
```

and i get `IOException`:

```
java.io.IOException: 400 error loading URL http://www.mysite.com/test.php?link=http://www.myothersite.com/test/test1-/10968/try.html?params=65%253A12%257C66%253A2%257C39%253A6%257C72%253A5104&rt=nc&_dmd=1&id=p3286.c0.m14&_vc=1&x=11&param1=p and d&sotto_categoria=_
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:362)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:338)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:136)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:125)
```

what could be the problem? can someone help me?thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved in a very simple way.. 
just remove black space in queryString replacing it with `-` :)

Comment: Thanks buddy.You save my day.